# How to implement the Read-Through Cache in Golang gracefully?

Tags: go, design-patterns, readability

In read-through, the logic(fetching data from the database and populating the cache) is usually supported by the library or stand-alone cache provider. Especially, we can utilize Annotations to implement this logic concisely, e.g.

```java
 @Cacheable(value="employees")  // it will cache result and key name will be "employees"
 public List<Employee> findAll() {
     return employeeDAO.findAll();
 }
```

I try to implement the `Cacheable` in Golang with a callback function, but I think my code is ugly.

```golang
// findAll returns a list of Employees
func findAll(orgnizationId int) []Employees {
    // encapsulate the employeeDAO API into a anonymous callback function,
    getFromDb := func() (interface{}, error) {
        result, err := employeeDAO.findAll(orgnizationId);
        return result, err
    }
  
    result, err := Cacheable(getFromDb, "employee_list_" + orgnizationId)

    if err != nil { // ...}

    // ...
    return result
}

func Cacheable(f func() (interface{}, error), cacheKey string) (interface{}, error) {
    tmp, err := cache.GetCacheValue(cacheKey)
    if err != nil { // ...}

    var data interface{}
    if tmp != "" {
    if err := jsoniter.UnmarshalFromString(tmp, &data); err != nil { // ...}
    }
    if data != nil {
        // Cache hit!
        return data, nil
    }

    // Cache miss, loads data from database
    data, err = f()
    if err != nil { // ...}
    
    // populates cache
    if err = cache.SetCacheValue(cacheKey, data, 600); err != nil {
        return data, err
    }

    return data, nil
}
```

I have to encapsulate the `employeeDAO` API into an anonymous callback function because the `Cacheable` function doesn't know how many parameters are necessary for loading data from a database. Even though the anonymous callback function knows where `orgnizationId` was defined, it is not readable if the anonymous function needs many variables defined out of its scope.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what feedback you're looking for. One thing I'd say is that your `Cacheable` function should take a data object in which to unmarshal the json from the cache, otherwise you can't end up with []Employee from the cache (only map[string]interface{}). A reasonable alternative (until we get generics early next year) is just to write out the uncacheing code with specific types, once for each dao you have.

Comment: @PaulHankin You are absolutely right. I have to transform `data interface{}` to concrete type to prevent returning `interface{}` constantly